# LD_PRELOAD does not loaded on systemd

Tags: linux, rhel, systemd, ld-preload

I am trying to inject a SO into a process that starts using systemd init system (using LD_PRELOAD), but it does not loaded into the new process.

I complied a basic SO (unrandom.c):

```
int rand(){
    return 42; //the most random number in the universe
}
```

with the command line:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC unrandom.c -o unrandom.so
```

I changed the .service file to include:

```
Environment="LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/unrandom.so"
```

After starting the service the LD_PRELOAD environment variable is exist in the process, but the SO does not injected

```
cat /proc/<PID>/maps
```

Am I missing something?

My machine is RHEL7

Comment: Does it work if you run in from a shell?

Comment: yes, If i'm running the command straight from shell it is working...

Comment: I would need to test that. I can give you a feedback in the evening. Btw, strange idea! :) May I ask why you are doing that?

Comment: is not a strange idea, I find myself trying to do the same because a bug workaround:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libpam-ldap/+bug/1418265

Comment: What is the process started with systemd? Is it statically or dynamically linked (check with `ldd /path/filename`), or is it script (check `head -1 /path/filename`) or is it suid program which will drop its LD_PRELOAD?

Comment: Are you sure the architectures of your .so and your program match? That is, are they both x86_64 or both i686?

Answer (score 4):

Setuid processes restrict usage of `LD_PRELOAD` (and some other env. variables) due to security reasons.

Loaded library must be specified via name only and be located in one of the directories listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf` (see e.g. [this link](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=59159)). For example on Debian-based systems

```
sudo cp library.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
LD_PRELOAD=library.so daemon
```

Another approach is to put full path to library to `/etc/ld.so.preload`:

```
sudo echo path/to/library.so >> /etc/ld.so.preload
```

but then it'll be preloaded to all new processes (which has a high chance of breaking your system if you are not extremely careful).

Comment: So what are the precise steps to preload?